# Calling FindWindowEx with program WIndowClass

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to use FindWindowEx to determine whether a certain program is running or not.

```
FindWindow(NULL, "Mozilla Firefox");
```

This works fine as long as I'm on firefox's start page. A workaround I found was:

```
FindWindow(NULL, "MozillaWindowClass");
```

But that left me wondering if that was specifically crafted for firefox, but it turns that it appeareantly works for other applications:

```
FindWindow(NULL, "OllyDbgWindowClass");
```

So my question is can I just use FindWindow with an argument like "**programXWindowClass**" for any program? Are there any exceptions to this?

Is "**programXWindowClass**" guaranteed to exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement for a caller to [RegisterClassEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexw) to follow any particular pattern, that maps a window class name to any other information (like the application name). Any caller can pick any valid window class name they like.

Keep in mind two notable consequences of this:

- A window class name need not be unique to any given application. All UWP applications use the window class "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow" by default, for example.
- A window class name can change across different versions of an application, or even different invocations of an application.

Answer (score 1):

> Is "programXWindowClass" guaranteed to exist?

No. What you observed is merely a coincidence in naming.